# How can I get the user's locale when running as root?

Tags: c++, macos, locale, setuid

I am running as root, but have the user's uid (e.g. `504`). How can I work out the user's locale (in my case `en_GB`)? The following does not work:

```
setuid(user_uid);
fprintf(stderr,
        CFStringGetCStringPtr(CFLocaleGetIdentifier(CFLocaleCopyCurrent()),
                              kCFStringEncodingMacRoman);
setuid(0);
```

This outputs `en_US` for me.

Comment: A user doesn't have a locale. Only an *environment* has a locale. The environment depends on many factors, though, and is usually set up by a series of shell scripts when a user logs in.

Comment: @KerrekSB Good point. Any idea how to get started in this situation?

Comment: @Crawl the user's directory, grep all files for occurrences of locale `export`s and anticipate what the user will type into her command line! Exhuming the `bash_history` file might give you statistical information about past behaviour; e.g. if you see lots of `LC_ALL=en_AU.utf8 ./myprog`, you know that the user might like kangaroos...

Comment: If it's really that much effort, how come `setuid(0)` is changing the result of `CFLocaleCopyCurrent()` but `setuid(user_uid)` isn't?

Comment: How is `setuid(0)` "changing" it? Usually when you obtain elevated privileges, the OS should reset or clear the entire environment so that unprivileged users can't inject anything into the privileged context. I assume that would set the locale to `C` or something like that.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's changing it to `en_US`, I'm not sure why. My colleague's Mac changes it to `en_GB`, which seems strange.

Comment: Hm, MacOSX might have some additional non-standard features that track a sort of system-wise locale default. In that case I woudln't know; we'll have to wait for some Macsperts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is contained in `GlobalPreferences.plist`, so running:

```
$ defaults read /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences AppleLocale
```

gives the desired result.

Answer (score -1):

You can't, because it doesn't exist.  The locale is controled by
environment variables, and can change dynamically, and from window to
window and even from application to application (i.e. if the user 
started a program with:

```
env LC_LANG=fr_FR program_name ...
```

.)  Under Unix, you might be able to get user's default locale by doing
something like:

```
FILE* in = popen( "su -c 'env | grep ^LC_ ; env | grep ^LANG' - user", "r" );
```

, then reading and parsing the input, but I don't think that there's
anything simpler.